# How to modify sudoers file with ansible?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ansible

We have a sudoers file in `/etc/sudoers.d/ops` (on 10 servers).  Sometimes we need to add multiple users and Cmnd_Alias to that file. How can we automate this with an ansible playbook?

Our sudoers file:

```
User_Alias     OPS_USERS = user1,user2,user3

Cmnd_Alias     OPS_CMD = /sbin/ifconfig, /usr/sbin/dmidecode

OPS_USERS      ALL = NOPASSWD:OPS_CMD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would go with a template module ([link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html)).
I would prepare a template somehow similar to this:

```
User_Alias     OPS_USERS = {{ users|join(', ') }}

Cmnd_Alias     OPS_CMD = {{ commands|join(', ') }}

OPS_USERS      ALL = NOPASSWD:OPS_CMD
```

And in variables I would put something like this:

```
users:
  - "user1"
  - "user2"
  - "user3"

commands: 
  - "/sbin/ifconfig"
  - "/usr/sbin/dmidecode"
```

Edit:
Maybe a little bit of explanation would be needed.

In template I used a filter that joins strings with given separator (**', '**). You can find more about filters [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-filters). Of course strings to concatenate are taken from the lists '**users**' or '**command**' defined in variables section of your play book.

Comment: That's Exactly What I Wanted , Thank you so much  :)